# TcpListener won't acknowledge connections

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

So I am writing a simple client-server application. It should send a packet, then wait to receive a packet, than send one etc... The problem is, it recieves the first packet, but when I start the `TcpListener` in the second iteration, it gives me this error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:13

```
private void listenForConnections()
    {
        bool prejelPaket = false; 
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress, port);
        listener.Start();

        while (!packetReceived)
        {
            try
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                listener.Stop();

                networkStream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] message = new byte[1024];
                networkStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                networkStream.Close();

                string strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
                packetReceived= true;
                MessageBox.Show("received message: " + strMessage);

                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                thListen.Join();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendPacket(object pClient)
    {
        string message = "test message;

        try
        {
            client = (TcpClient)pClient;
            client.Connect(IPAddress, port);
            networkStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] strMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            networkStream.Write(strMessage, 0, strMessage.Length);           
            networkStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the client / networkstream once.  Store them in a property until you are finished sending and receiving.  Then close and dispose.  Do not stop / close the connection between each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Move the

```
listener.Stop();
```

outside the while loop.

EDIT: to explain why

The reason why it works the first time but second iteration fails is because after the first client is accepted from `client = listener.AcceptTcpClient()` the next line of code calls `listener.Stop()` which stops listening for connections. Any subsequent calls to `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. Moving `listener.Stop()` outside the while loop only stops listening for connections once it exits the loop.

Looking at it again `packetReceived` is set to true in the first iteration as well, so it's going to exit the while loop after the first client anyway, is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: I think you're wrong, AcceptTcpClient() blocks the thread until a client connects, so when it is connected, it just stops the listener.

Comment: Is that not very the problem you are having? If not I have misunderstood your problem.